What can I do if there's no matching EdgeDriver version for my Microsoft Edge?
I wanted to download Microsoft Edge WebDriver for Edge version 127.0.2651.74 installed in my Kubuntu VM.

I went to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/ to download it, but I couldn't find a Linux driver for my version (under Get the latest version section).

Under Recent versions section, the driver is available for version 127.0.2651.72.

Can I use that version or should I install .72 Edge version (is that even possible?) and use that driver? Or use the Dev channel for the driver?

"Can I use..."? Why not just try it and see what happens? It's a VM, take a snapshot if you're worried about breaking it.

I used the 127.0.2651.72 version WebDriver with .74 version browser and my Java code (using Selenium libraries) worked fine.

If you really want to use matching versions of browser and WebDriver in Linux, there are only two options:

Using older version Edge which has a corresponding WebDriver (but I guess it's not possible since Microsoft is not having a page with old version download links for the browser)
Found this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/download where you can find older versions but it's for "Microsoft Edge for Business". I'm not sure if it's the same as regular Edge.


Using Dev channel since it has a corresponding WebDriver version (as of July 29, 2024).

But since there will be a new version every week in the Dev channel, I'm not sure if Microsoft will provide WebDriver for every version.


I tried to find documentation from Microsoft regarding using old version of WebDriver, but couldn't find it. From the looks of it, Microsoft isn't prioritising providing WebDriver for every version in Linux.
Kinda related discussion on GitHub: No latest stable release for Linux #156
